# How to create case for Microsoft support on SharePoint related issue?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We need Microsoft confirmation on one specific configuration in production SQL server.

How we can check whether we have already Microsoft support to raise the case?

In case if we don't have support from MS, how I can raise the case ?

Where can I get the software assurance I'd?

Thanks

Comment: We are using SharePoint 2013 standard edition.

Answer (score 2):

You can open support cases at https://support.microsoft.com/. On the lower left is a 'Get More Support' where you can open cases.

Answer (score 2):

We recommend you contact Microsoft Customer Support Services (CSS) via telephone so that a dedicated Support Professional can assist you in a more efficient manner. Please be advised that you might be charged for phone support service. Here are the Phone Support numbers of Customer Service Representative(CSR) for the different regions:

1. If you are located in US or Canada, please call 1-800-936-4900;

2· If you are located in India, please call 1-800-419-5666;

3· If you are located in other countries or regions, please go to the website (http://support.microsoft.com/select/?target=assistance ) by selecting the product and following the wizard to create a new Phone Service Request to Microsoft Phone Support team. 
         
Hope above helps.